# Disabling editing of a product <input> field in Magento's "manage products" area?

Tags: php, magento

In Magento Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Products, I'd like to disable a couple of product fields so that administrators can't edit them.

Essentially turning this:
[image]

into this: [image]

Magento pulls the field HTML in via the template at `adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml`, via the function `getElementHtml()` but I can't find the place where the actual `<input>` HTML is being constructed.

Besides, there's probably a more modular way of doing this, rather than just editing the template's HTML.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered a similar question, here, which led me to the solution:

1. Open up `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\form\renderer\fieldset\element.phtml`
2. Find the line which reads `<?php $this->checkFieldDisable() ?>`
3. Underneath this, insert this block (edit "sku" to whatever you need):

`<?php`

`// Disable editing of SKU field`

`if ($_element->name == "sku") {`

`$_element->setDisabled(true);`

`}`

`?>`

There may be an even more elegant way of doing this, such as setting the "disabled" option somewhere in the database, but since these are system attributes I doubt it. This works!

Comment: Setting the attribute as locked will work, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7874345/394589