# Disable SKU attribute in admin Magento 2

Tags: php, events, product, magento2, disabled-input

I'm trying to make product SKU attribute not editable in Admin Products->Inventory->Catalog.

I'm using this previous response as an example: [Magento read-only and hidden product attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384120/magento-read-only-and-hidden-product-attributes/7874345#7874345)

I've created an Observer to use lockAttribute("attribute_code") method.

Here is the **Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml**:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_edit_action">
        <observer name="vendor_admin_lock" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ProductLockAttributes" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And in **ProductLockAttributes.php**:

```
class ProductLockAttributes implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();
        $product->lockAttribute('sku');
        $product->lockAttribute('sku_type');
    }
}
```

The event gets called but in the admin interface when editing a product the SKU is still editable.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see this answer about making attributes read-only: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/188368/14866